# Why the 'Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory' type initializer exception when using NET40-NoCastle?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

So I copied the [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) from the Moq home page pretty much verbatim, and am getting a castle proxy exception.

Here's my code (as a console app for an easier sample)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Moq;

namespace MoqTestConsole
{
    public interface ILoveThisFramework
    {
        bool DownloadExists(string s);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mock<ILoveThisFramework> mock = new Mock<ILoveThisFramework>();

            // WOW! No record/replay weirdness?! :)
            mock.Setup(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0")).Returns(true);

            // Hand mock.Object as a collaborator and exercise it, 
            // like calling methods on it...
            ILoveThisFramework lovable = mock.Object;
            bool download = lovable.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0");

            // Verify that the given method was indeed called with the expected value
            mock.Verify(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Everything compiles nicely, but when it calls `mock.Object` The following exception is thrown.

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  Message=The type initializer for 'Moq.Mock`1' threw an exception.
  Source=Moq
  TypeName=Moq.Mock`1
  StackTrace:
       at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.Generic.cs:line 138
       at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action) in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\PexProtector.cs:line 56
       at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.Generic.cs:line 136
       at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.Generic.cs:line 153
       at Moq.Mock.GetObject() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.cs:line 152
       at Moq.Mock.get_Object() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.cs:line 147
       at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.Generic.cs:line 131
       at MoqTestConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Test\MoqTestConsole\MoqTestConsole\Program.cs:line 25
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       Message=The type initializer for 'Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory' threw an exception.
       Source=Moq
       TypeName=Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory
       StackTrace:
            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..ctor()
            at Moq.Mock`1..cctor() in d:\Code\moq\src\Source\Mock.Generic.cs:line 54
       InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
            Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
            Source=Moq
            FileName=Castle.Core, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
            FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = jsi-dev-001\jmacintyre
LOG: DisplayName = Castle.Core, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/Test/MoqTestConsole/MoqTestConsole/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Moq, Version=4.0.10827.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Castle.Core, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/Test/MoqTestConsole/MoqTestConsole/bin/Debug/Castle.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/Test/MoqTestConsole/MoqTestConsole/bin/Debug/Castle.Core/Castle.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/Test/MoqTestConsole/MoqTestConsole/bin/Debug/Castle.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/Test/MoqTestConsole/MoqTestConsole/bin/Debug/Castle.Core/Castle.Core.EXE.

            StackTrace:
                 at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..cctor()
            InnerException:
```

So it appears to be a Castle Proxy component that's missing, but I'm referencing the binary from the `NET40-NoCastle` directory.

Latest version of Moq (Moq.4.0.10827)

And I'm new to Moq, so I may be doing something extremely dense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was using the NET40-NoCastle binaries, which apparently means you are using Castle Windsor and already have the Castle Windsor binaries in your project.  I had the misassumption this directory was for *projects* that *don't* use Castle Windsor.

Anyway, bottom line, if you're have this same issue, **use the binaries from the NET40 directories instead.**

Thanks [Ben Alabaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40650/benalabaster) for the answer via Twitter.

Comment: I made the same mistake, it's not the best naming I've seen

Comment: I just did exactly the same thing as well. Directory naming fail I'm afraid.